# How to quickly find match with different string lengths

Tags: sql

I've been trying to come up with some psuedo logic to figure out the following.

I have a table with about a hundred thousand records

The primary key is the ID such as

```
ID, col1, col2, col3

A3242X,,,
B323X,,,
A3242Y,,,
Y32YXX,,,
```

Now I have user input such as   `A3242XABC123` and `Y32` and ... and ...

My output is to figure out all records in the table where 
the ID in the table begins with any of the input values  OR
any of the input values begin with any values in the Id table.

In this case the output would be

```
A3242X  (ID A3242XABC123 begins with this)     and 

Y32YXX  (the input Y32 begins with this).
```

My thoughts are that I would loop thru the input values, compare and then subtract a char from end....such as

```
search_var=A3242XABC123;

Loop

  select id from table where value = search_var;

  if found exit;

  search_var = substr(search_var, 0,length(search_var-1));

end;
```

--Basically loop thru until find value.

--For second scenario I think I can just do somethign like

```
search_var[1] = A3242XABC123;

search_var[2] = Y32YXX;

for i = 1 to 2 loop

select id from table where id begins search_var;

add id to result array;

end;
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to do this.  In most cases the user will only enter maybe up to a few dozen ID's.

Comment: Why do you tag all these languages when your question should be sql only?

Comment: @Tim - surely a cry for attention.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the array and put the vars into a table.  You can then do something like:

```
select *
from t cross join
     vars
     on t.id like concat(vars.val, '%') or
        vars.val like concat(t.id, '%')
```

In SQL Server, you can even do:

```
with vars as (select 'var1' as val union all
              select 'var2' as val union all
              . . . 
             )
select *
from t cross join
     vars
     on t.id like vars.val + '%' or
        vars.val like t.id + '%'
```

Comment: Gordon, Thank you.   I'm not sure I"m going to have the ability to add the inputs into a table and do a cross join. But that might be a possiblity. But, I need to try and solve this outside of that solution. Thanks, I appreciate it though!   Hi Tim, I'm looking for logic, This actually is not specific to SQL and my table could reside in a Java Memory as a hash or anything else. I was looking for logic in any language thus the tagging.  Something in perl or python would probably work best for me.